# Rotate Perspective in Ortho

Tags: modeling

So when you push the numpad 3 key in ortho you swap to side view, is there a way to rotate my view 45 degrees from that view on the y axis? I am trying to use the knife project and would like to know how to rotate my camera in future scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the view in the Y-axis in 15 degrees increments by holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> and scrolling the mousewheel up/down.